# How to parse a yaml of lists in it using golang?

Tags: go, yaml, unmarshalling

Example yaml file `final-result.yml`:

```yaml
- category: 1
  rules:
  - name: a
    results:
    - asset: b
      advice: c

- category: 2
  rules:
  - name: d
    results:
    - asset: e
      advice: f
```

I tried package `gopkg.in/yaml.v2` to unmarshal:

```golang
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type FinalResult struct {
    category string      `yaml:"category"`
    rules    []RulesItem `yaml:"rules,flow"`
}

type RulesItem struct {
    name    string        `yaml:"name"`
    results []ResultsItem `yaml:"results,flow"`
}

type ResultsItem struct {
    asset  string `yaml:"asset"`
    advice string `yaml:"advice"`
}

func main() {
    var result []FinalResult

    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("final-result.yml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
        return
    }
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(content, &result)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to parse file ", err)
    }

    log.Println(result)
}
```

But it gives an empty result:

`[{ []} { []}]`

Comment: From the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2?utm_source=godoc#Unmarshall) "Struct fields are only unmarshalled if they are exported (have an upper case first letter)". So start exporting your variables; e.g. `Category string`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2?utm_source=godoc#Unmarshall) you should make the struct fields public in order for unmarshal to correctly populate the data.:

> Struct fields are only unmarshalled if they are exported (have an upper case first letter)

Your code works as expected after changing the type definitions as follows:

```golang
type FinalResult struct {
    Category string      `yaml:"category"`
    Rules    []RulesItem `yaml:"rules,flow"`
}

type RulesItem struct {
    Name    string        `yaml:"name"`
    Results []ResultsItem `yaml:"results,flow"`
}

type ResultsItem struct {
    Asset  string `yaml:"asset"`
    Advice string `yaml:"advice"`
}
```